Use of volume nodes for hair shader
The papers Physically-accurate fur reflectance: modeling, measurement and rendering and An efficient and practical near and far field fur reflectance model discuss physically based fur shading and describe hair fibers and fur fibers having an inner structure called the medulla which is more significant in fur. The medulla behaves like a volume and scatters light. Would connecting the Volume Scatter node to the Principled Hair shader's volume output make render times really slow?

Sure, it will make it slower. But what is "really slow"? Hard to predict because it depends on your scene, the amount of hair, how transmissive it is, the volume density, the bounce settings and everything else that will interact with the hair, lights, environment, other objects...
